# How to display multiline cells in QTableView with QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I have a QSqlTableModel with a table from a MySQL database, which I use to populate a table view with setModel function, this works fine but I want multiline cells in all rows of one column in order to be able to display some columns info of that row insted of display all the columns. Here is an example of my current table and what I want.

Current table and desired table
[image: Current table and desired table]

Here is an actual example:
Table with multiple lines in cells of one column
[image: Table with multiple lines in cells of one column]

Does anyone know how to achieve this with a QTableView and QSqlTableModel as source to fill the table view?

Can this be done subclassing QStyledItemDelegate? If so, could someone show me an example to understand it? I don't know how to access and select data of some columns of my QSqlTableModel and put it in a QTableView  cell.

Comment: I'm not sure about this comment but may be "QTableView::resizeRowsToContents()" helps to reach what you desired. If so let me know.

Comment: @saeed I think QTableView::resizeRowsToContents() could be useful if the text was a simple large string , but it is not, the text comes from mysql table which is displayed in the tableview with qsqltablemodel, so the problem is how can I select the text from the sql table and put it in the tableview since I can't control this, I just use tableview->setModel(qsqlmodel) in order to display the data in the tableview